# Using ActiveRecord.create with belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, associations

I'm using Rails 3.1 and have a simple transaction class that references a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :transactions, :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
   belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
   attr_accessible :amount
end
```

The database schema is

```
create_table "transactions", :force => true do |t|
   t.decimal "amount"
   t.integer "sender_id", :null => false
   t.integer "recipient_id", :null => false
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
end
```

I would like to create a set of initial transactions in the `seeds.rb`, but the underlying `INSERT` is never generated with foreign keys for the `sender_id` and `recipient_id`.  The signature of the method is:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :022 >   Transaction.method(:create) => 
   #<Method: Transaction(id: integer, 
                         amount: decimal,
                         sender_id: integer,
                         recipient_id: integer)
   (ActiveRecord::Base).create>
```

I've tried both

```
Transaction.create(
  amount:                0.50,
  sender:                User.first,
  recipient:             User.last,
)
```

and

```
Transaction.create(
  amount:                0.50,
  sender_id:             User.first.id,
  recipient_id:          User.last.id,
)
```

In each case, the `INSERT` statement is

```
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `transactions` (`amount`, `recipient_id`, `sender_id`) 
             VALUES (0.75, NULL, NULL)
```

I'm new to rails, so I'm sure this is a misunderstanding on my part, but I have not been able to find a solution from my reading of the rails docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution.  I just needed to change the `attr_accessible` line in the Transaction model to

```
attr_accessible :amount, :sender, :recipient
```

and all is well.